# How to know the coding behind the HTML tags?

Tags: html, function, methods, tags

Kindly go through this post because it is totally a new one of it's type.

I am very curious about knowing the code behind the HTML tags.
For example, 
If I want to know the code behind the underline tag i.e. the u tag of HTML, then from where can I get it.

Any suggestions? From where to learn all this?

Actually, I want to make my own functions similar to HTML tags but in some other language.

Waiting for the earliest positive response.

Regards
greatdevaks

Comment: Are you looking for reference materials?

Answer (score 0):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) is a pretty good (and reliable!) resource for HTML documentation.